# SQLalchemy: ProductVariant.attributesrelated - there are no foreign keys linking these tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

While I am trying to migrate saleor's product models(https://github.com/mirumee/saleor/blob/master/saleor/product/models.py) which is in django to fastapi(sqlalchemy), I got following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition
> between parent/child tables on relationship
> ProductVariant.attributesrelated - there are no foreign keys linking
> these tables. Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a
> ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin'
> expression.

Since, there are many connections in the table, I felt difficulty in solving the error I get.

```
class Product(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    assigned_product_attributes = relationship(
        "AssignedProductAttribute", back_populates="product"
    )
    product_variants = relationship("ProductVariant", back_populates="product")
    attribute_products = relationship(
        "AttributeProduct",
        secondary=AssignedProductAttribute.__tablename__,
        back_populates="assigned_products",
    )

class ProductVariant(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    sku = Column(String(32), unique=True)
    product_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("product.id"))
    product = relationship("Product", back_populates="product_variants")
    attributes = relationship("AssignedVariantAttribute", back_populates="variant")
    attributesrelated = relationship(
        "AttributeVariant", back_populates="assigned_variants"
    )

class AttributeVariant(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    attribute_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attribute.id"))
    product_type_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("producttype.id"))
    assigned_variants_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("producttype.id"))

    attribute = relationship("Attribute", back_populates="attributevariant")
    product_type = relationship("ProductType", back_populates="attributevariant")
    assigned_variants = relationship(
        "ProductVariant",
        secondary=AssignedVariantAttribute.__tablename__,
        back_populates="attributesrelated",
    )
    variantassignments = relationship(
        "AssignedVariantAttribute", back_populates="assignment"
    )

class AssignedVariantAttribute(Base, TimestampMixin):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    variant_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("productvariant.id"))
    assignment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attributevariant.id"))
    values_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("attributevalue.id"))

    variant = relationship("ProductVariant", back_populates="attributes")
    assignment = relationship("AttributeVariant", back_populates="variantassignments")
    values = relationship(
        "AttributeValue",
        secondary=AssignedVariantAttributeValue.__tablename__,
        back_populates="variantassignments",
    )
    variantvalueassignment = relationship(
        "AssignedVariantAttributeValue", back_populates="assignment"
    )
```

UPDATE

this is the django equivalent from saleor

```
class ProductVariant(SortableModel, ModelWithMetadata):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(
        Product, related_name="variants", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )

class BaseAssignedAttribute(models.Model):
    assignment = None

class AssignedVariantAttribute(BaseAssignedAttribute):
    """Associate a product type attribute and selected values to a given variant."""

    variant = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductVariant, related_name="attributes", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assignment = models.ForeignKey(
        "AttributeVariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="variantassignments"
    )
    values = models.ManyToManyField(
        "AttributeValue",
        blank=True,
        related_name="variantassignments",
        through=AssignedVariantAttributeValue,
    )

class AttributeVariant(SortableModel):
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(
        "Attribute", related_name="attributevariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    product_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ProductType, related_name="attributevariant", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    assigned_variants = models.ManyToManyField(
        ProductVariant,
        blank=True,
        through=AssignedVariantAttribute,
        through_fields=("assignment", "variant"),
        related_name="attributesrelated"
    )
```

Comment: There is no ForeignKey Constraint between ProductVariant and AttributeVariant. So the relationship `attributesrelated` cannot be resolved. Probably you want to use AssignedVariantAttribute as a secondary table for the relationship. Please have a look to mimimize the question to the related parts as it's totally unclear. Maybe also add a visual indication about how the tables should be linked (Use a database visualiser on the existing database of saleor).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Is it okay if I put saleor models that is in django?

Comment: Yes, but please post as minimal as possible (see [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for some guidelines). Try to narrow it down to where the issue is.

Comment: @rfkortekaas I have updated and tried to post as minimal as I can but the models are related to many other table and I am not sure if the information will be lesser to figure out so I might have put a bit more than needed.

Comment: Have a look at [Association object](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) as `ProductVariant` is related to `AttributeVariant` via the secondary object `AssignedVariantAttribute`. Probably it's enought to change to this: `attributesrelated = relationship("AssignedVariantAttribute", back_populates="assigned_variants")`